# PC randomly turns off and back on every 1 sec-1 min

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

The problem started few days ago.
Normally I don't turn off my PC, and it’s always working.

I was just surfing around the Internet when my PC shut down and turned back on again and started this circle on-off with a random delay, sometimes immediately sometimes during 1-5 minutes (even loads Windows), sometimes before the BIOS "beep", sometimes after...

I thought that it’s the CPU overheating or something, so I changed thermal paste, but didn’t turn on the PC for a couple hours after. After I finally turned the PC on; it worked around 2-3 hours normally and then it started again, but this time thermal paste didn’t help any more.

I tried taking out and swapping memmory cards, tried disconnecting HDD, tried disconnecting GPU, I even went to some PC store that gave me some used PSU to test and give it back after. They claimed the PSU they gave me to test is 100% in good condition. All of these attempts to find the issue had the same result.

I noticed in BIOS that my processor is 45 °C-49 °C. (My processor is i7-3770K.)

ALSO I noticed just NOW while writing this I turned my head to my PC table and I've seen my mouse (it has LED light changing colors) that connected to PC blink like 3 times!  (I’m writing from a laptop.)

Comment: Sounds like you tested everything that could be related so in my opinion, that leaves the motherboard. It's very much possible that it could be faulty.

Comment: @Moses i just noticed that my mouse blins sometimes when connected to turned off pc . at least it means its 100% not the CPU. Could it be motherboard ? or maybe in store they gave me a bad PSU and my PSU shorts?

Comment: Changed the thermal paste? If you thought to change the thermal paste, then it also sounds like you are the installer of the CPU originally. If you are not the original installer of the CPU and it was factory set, then that was a bad move. How old is your PC? Used? Refurb? HP? Dell? Prefab? You built it? But this does sound like something that happened to me. It turned out to be the RAM not fully seated correctly, after I upgraded RAM. Also just make sure all is plugged in correctly and snug. Using surge protector?